# Is there probation after the full sentence is served?

Tags: prison-architect

After an inmate serves his full sentence, is there any sort of probation or supervision where they will have to report, and get permission to move out of state?

Comment: This... is a question about a game, right? I was unaware this feature existed in Prison Architect.

Comment: @Fluttershy I've said it before, but this site has the *best* question titles. I'm actually kind of curious how regularly we show up as a false positive to the NSA/FBI/ATF/whatnot...

Answer (score 4):

No.

When a prisoner have served his sentence, he will automatically be released.
He will head for the exit, and leave the prison.

This is also only for the current version. In a future version there might be some work to do, when a prisoner leaves your prison.